# Using OpenIdConnect without specifying metadata endpint

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, openid-connect

I am developing a relying party in a ASP.Net MVC C# that should authenticate in a external Identity Provider, I am using the owin library from Microsoft. The issue I am having is that the Idp doesn't expose the metadata endpoint and even if I don't specify it in the configuration an exception is thrown when I try to contact the Idp.

> [InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain
>   configuration from:
>   'https://domain.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]

I have the following code snippet:

```
            var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
            options.AuthenticationType = authenticationType;            
            options.ClientId = clientConfiguration.ClientID;
            options.ClientSecret = AppSettings.ClientSecret;            
            options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n => ReceiveValidSecurityToken(n),
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n => ROSAddProtocolToken(n, clientConfiguration),
                AuthenticationFailed = n => AuthenticationFailed(n),
            };
            options.Authority = AppSettings.Authority;

            options.RedirectUri = clientConfiguration.GetPostLoginRedirectUri(clientConfiguration.CurrentCulture).ToString();
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.Scope = AppSettings.Scope;
            options.ClientSecret = clientConfiguration.ClientSecret;

            options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType;
```

My question is, how to I specify all the endpoints in the MS Owin lib (Authorization, Token, UserInfo, Jwls)?

The Idp is expecting the following settings:
scope: openid
Http Binding: GET
Response Type: code
token endpoint auth method: client_secret_jwt

Comment: Are you running your Idp ?  Also, is this Idp configured with the `ResponseType` and `Scope` as mentioned above. The error says.. Client is unable to communicate with Idp.

Comment: Are you able to access the idp discovery document using the link in  `AppSettings.Authority` ?

Comment: I have updated the post with the Idp specs. Idp is external to our company, I can't change it. The metadata endpoint is blocked, I can't retrieve the metadata using the browser for example.

Comment: I think your domain has no access to Idp. It may be an access/firewall issue. I would check with the idp first. It could be with the certificate as well.

Comment: That's not the problem. The idp doesn't expose the metadata endpoint at all, the external company said they don't allow discovery and so they blocked it on purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after some hours I figured out how to specify the endpoints.

```
var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
            options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
            {
                AuthorizationEndpoint = AppSettings.Authority + "/" + AutorizationEndpointSufix,                
                JwksUri = AppSettings.Authority + "/" + JwksEndpointSufix,
                TokenEndpoint = AppSettings.Authority + "/" + TokenEndpointSufix,
                UserInfoEndpoint = AppSettings.Authority + "/" + UserInfoEndpointSufix,
                Issuer = AppSettings.Authority

            };
```

If you instantiate the Configuration property then It will ignore the Metadata. I manage to get a response from the authorize endpoint, just wondering how to trigger the token endpoint, any idea?